# Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_osp65apb'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page

Tags: load

Sir ,i have publish the simple asp website using file system and i am getting this error ,first i have a large code in web.config file but, then i was got the error 500,but when i delete most of code in web.config then i got above message ,please solve my problem ,i am new at ur  website, thanks in advance.....Server Error in '/hosteddomains/makemytest.in' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_osp65apb'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="_Default, App_Web_osp65apb" %>
Line 2:
Line 3:

Source File: /hosteddomains/makemytest.in/makeview/default.aspx    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237